# Pass POST variables automatically

Tags: php, forms, variables, post

is it possible to pass $_POST[] variables automatically, without pressing a submit button?

Comment: Use `jQuery` for this! [.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: You need to better explain what you would like to do, because the answer as it stands is no!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this submit the form using `$("#form").submit();`

Answer (score 2):

You can even achieve this with Javascript.

```
document.forms["yourForm"].submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), if you don't want to submit through the form submit.